# How to solve the following trigonometric quadratic equation for x

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

How to solve the following trigonometric quadratic equation for x

$3 \cos x + r \cos^{2} x - 2 \sin x -r \sin^{2} x = 0$

where r is a constant

Even though this trigonometric quadratic equation has only one variable(i.e. x), it seems that it has two variables due to the two trigonometric ratios  (sin x and cos x)

How to proceed in solving the problem?Is it even possible to solve this problem?

Comment: What can you do with the $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ term?

Comment: it will become $ cos2x $ then what?

Comment: Wait, sorry. Are you looking for a numerical solution or an analytic one?

Comment: I am looking for an analytic solution.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490344/homework-problem

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u = \cos x$. Then you have
$$3u+r u^2 - \sqrt{1-u^2} - r(1-u^2) = 0$$
rearrange to get
$$(3u+2ru^2-r)^2 = 1 - u^2$$
For a general $r$ you'll have a quartic equation. These can be solved but may not make sense here, given $r$. For example you must have a solution $u$ that is in $[-1,1]$ or it won't make any sense. Also you may need to be careful because we implicitly assumed that $\sin x$ was positive which may be false (in which case your equation changes slightly).